# Partitions for vpc flow logs

Tags: amazon-athena

This query works as expected.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vpc_flow_logs3 (
  version int,
  account string,
  interfaceid string,
  sourceaddress string,
  destinationaddress string,
  sourceport int,
  destinationport int,
  protocol int,
  numpackets int,
  numbytes bigint,
  starttime int,
  endtime int,
  action string,
  logstatus string
)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LOCATION 's3://todel162/AWSLogs/XXXXX/vpcflowlogs/us-east-1/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

But if I add the parition clause as suggested in the documentation, it does not read a single row. (Table is created successfully though)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html

In other words I am not able to use partitions using this clause in create table statement.

> PARTITIONED BY (dt string)

How do I create a table with partitions for vpc flow logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create a partitioned table you also need to add partitions to it. For partitioned tables the `LOCATION` property does not point to the table's data. A newly created partitioned table is essentially empty.

There are many ways to add partitions to a partitioned table. The VPC flow logs don't follow the Hive partitioning scheme, which means that you can't use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to load all partitions. Instead you have to manually list all partitions and add them either using Glue's `BatchCreatePartition` API call, or using Athena by running `ALTER TABLE vpc_flow_logs3 ADD PARTITION …`. You can find an example of how to do it for the flow logs in step 4 of the guide you linked to.